# Django NoReverseMatch and auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, login-required

Im dealing with a simple login app here. I can log in and logout perfectly. What is happening is that when i log out and i want to test what happens if try to go to a page that only log in users can see i´m getting a NoReverseMatch Exception. I look at the docs and:
'The NoReverseMatch exception is raised by django.core.urlresolvers when a matching URL in your URLconf cannot be identified based on the parameters supplied.'
this are my urls:

```
url(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),

url(r'^index/', login_required(Index.as_view(template_name= "index.html")), name = 'index'),

url(r'^logout/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logout.html'}),
```

The problem is that i don´t know where i have to set the url for users that want to go to a protected url without logging in. I already tried the "Login_required" (as you can see in the urls), i tried with other mixins like 'LoginRequiredMixin' from braces, and Stronghold. And none of those worked. All i wanto to do is to redirect those users(the ones that are not logged in and try to cheat the system) to the loging.html. I have this in my settings.py maybe it helps:

```
APPEND_SLASH = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

LOGIN_URL = 'login'


LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'


LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

I know that this question maybe is to wide, for that i´m sorry.
Any other information that you need let me know. Than you very much

EDIT: this is what django is showing:

> NoReverseMatch at /Exi/index/
>   Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    SO doesn´t let me show the links here
>   Django Version: 1.6.5
>   Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
>   Exception Value:
>   Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
>   Exception Location: C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 452
>   Python Executable:  C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 2.7.6
>   Python Path:
>   ['C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\ExiAdmin',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\site-packages\mysql_python-1.2.5-py2.7-win32.egg',
>    'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\plat-win',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\lib-tk',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\Scripts',
>    'C:\Python27\Lib',
>    'C:\Python27\DLLs',
>    'C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene',
>    'C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\site-packages']

Comment: The NoReverseMatch has nothing to do with authentication. You should show the full error, so we can see what parameters are failing to be matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `name='login'` to the end of the login URL definition, in the same way as you have done with the index one. And similarly for the logout URL.

Comment: You are awesome. Seriously, you have answered every django question y read in SO. Thanks man.